# How to set grease pencil objects priority

Tags: grease-pencil

I'm struggling with grease pencil objects. I've created a grease pencil object called Background containing some flat colors. Then I have another grease pencil object called Moon containing the drawing of a moon with a glow effect. Finally I would like to draw some trees on top of that through another grease pencil object. However my trees are drawn behind the moon instead being in front of it. I'm guessing then, how to prioritize between objects ? How to define which object is drawn first, and so on ?

Thanks !

Comment: Objects are in 3D space, just move it back by a small amount.  You can Arrange strokes and fills that are on the same layer, but I think Objects need to be moved in 3D space.

Comment: Thank you your advice !